# angular 4+ Failed to compile. File size is greater than possible Buffer: 0x7fffffff bytes

Tags: image, angular, assets, angular5

I'm new to Angular and try to put images and videos in template but I don't know the appropriate folder to put them. first when put them in **"src"** folder and put  it's shows empty picture and said couldn't load image in the console, But when use the same url in css **background-img** property it's works fine. After that I put images and videos inside **assets** folder, But now both **angular 4 and 5** crashed with error: 

**Failed to compile.

File size is greater than possible Buffer: 0x7fffffff bytes.**
I didn't what I missing... it's work once I put one image in **assets** folder but when I put more images this error came up.
Can any one help me to show where to put images and videos and load them in my components??
 I'm on **mac osX. angular-cli 1.5.3, webpack: 3.8.1, node 6.11.4** 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get this fixed finally? You were probably putting more assets than angular can handle. I faced this problem when a had copied a 7GB music directory into assets

Comment: @rhino2rhonda No I didn't fixed it. I tried so hard  but I cant and I don't know why this limitation. first I thought that limitation coming from Mac OS but the same error accrued in Ubuntu 16.4.  I think I missed some thing and also I'm wondering cause no one answer me or asked the same question :(

Comment: @rhino2rhonda I got it now. assets folder is made for small stuff as favico and some basic logos. what I trying to do is to put video files in this dierctory but now I know those video files should be in the server and angular app only for making GUI :)